# Applications to learn Jquery API's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me some web or mobile applications or games? 
So i can try them in java script and jquery api's. I want to become good programmer in java script and jquery. your experience will be useful to me. hoping for help.

would be grateful for help...thanks in advance,,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may Use [visualjquery](http://visualjquery.com/) to go through the list of available features and use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to test them easily.
You can also try http://codylindley.com/jqueryselectors/

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear about what exactly you are looking for. Are you asking for suggestions of what mobile applications or games you could write in Javascript and jQuery? If so, you won't be very lucky. Javascript allows making web pages dynamic and jQuery builds on it to provide a quicker to use framework of basic manipulations.
Games have been written in jQuery but the engines running Javascript are currently not strong or reliable enough to make it an enjoyable experience beyond games like Pairs.

If you are looking for things to make in Javascript just to learn it a bit, maybe you could try building a page with a square which you can move with the arrow keys.